# How to get type from nested object's properties in typescript

Tags: typescript

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface FooBar {
  foo: string
  bar: {
    baz: string
  }
}
```

I'd like to construct a type based `FooBar`'s `bar` property, with only its properties:

```
interface Bar {
  baz: string
}
```

Trying `Pick<Foobar, 'bar'>` only yields:

```
{
  bar: {
    baz: string
  }
}
```

Comment: Does this do what you want? `type Bar = FooBar["bar"]`

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes! Would you like to put this as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to a property inside a type with square brackets:

```
type Bar = FooBar["bar"];

const example: Bar = {
   baz: 'hi'
};
```